# Hexo inject html

Tags: hexo

I have been given a task to add a Mailchimp signup form to a hexo generated page.

It is my first time using hexo and I can't understand how to add html to it.

At the moment I have generated a a .ejs file called signupform and I pasted the mailchimp html there. Then in the layout .ejs file that has the footer I put a

tag that has a link. That link links to /signupform. Do I need to generate a .md file for it aswell? How do I link to it?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that in /source where the different pages are I can just create a new folder for a page. Then create index.md and Whatever html I write there is translated to html on the webpage. Be mindful of indentation though.